# Why float and text-align behave different in a td?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Following is my table structure:

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="new_doc" colspan="7">
            Add a New Document
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Sl</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Path</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Share</th>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the content of the td with class **new_doc** to be right aligned.

Initially I tried with `float:right;` which gave me an unexpected result. But when I tried with `text-align: right;` it gave me the desired output.

Why they are behaving entirely different for a td ?

Following are the fiddle:

[**float: right**](http://jsfiddle.net/QrQZW/)

[**text-align: right**](http://jsfiddle.net/QrQZW/1/)

Comment: `float` on a table cell; now that's a new one to me. `float` determines the placements of block elements, and in particular, how they wrap around other elements or text. It probably won't work on a table cell like that, and in fact, without looking, I wouldn't have any idea what it would do.

Comment: What's wrong with: http://jsfiddle.net/QrQZW/2/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan There is nothing wrong in it. Just wanted to know why this difference happened.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham I got the impression that *you tried to do something about text alignments* like stated in your Q. But I see no point in doing anything, though yes, Bolt answered you pretty well!

Comment: @icktoofay: CSS does say that floating an element should automatically transform it into a block box regardless of what you set its `display` to. So it will "work" on elements that aren't currently being displayed as blocks - just not as the author might expect. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables and table cells have a unique formatting structure which, in CSS, [is described in an entire section of its own](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html).

Attempting to float a table cell will interfere with this structure, as it quite literally causes it to no longer be a table cell — it turns it into a block box instead, causing HTML attributes such as `colspan` as in your markup to no longer apply:

> **Note.** Positioning and floating of table cells can cause them not to be table cells anymore, according to the rules in [section 9.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). When floating is used, the rules on anonymous table objects may cause an anonymous cell object to be created as well.

Browsers following the CSS spec on formatting tables have to follow specific rules on how to handle such cases in order to preserve a relatively sane table structure according to the [CSS table formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display). Specifically, what you see when using `float` is that the first `td`, which is now a (floating) block box, is automatically contained in an anonymous table cell within the first `tr`. Note that this anonymous cell *does not* inherit the `colspan` attribute from your markup; the attribute simply stops applying altogether. Since there are no other cells in the first `tr`, the rest of it is left blank. Once the first `tr` has been formatted, the second `tr` is then constructed as normal.

Of course, since you're looking to align the *text* content of your table cell, it only makes sense to use the `text-align` property to do so.