# Using CSS alone, can you float each cell in a table column into the top of the respective row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Suppose I have a table built using the standard `<table>` HTML element, and it looks like this (conceptually speaking):

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 
--------|----
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
--------|----
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
-------------
```

Using ONLY CSS, can I get it to display like this?

```
---------
| 3     |
| 1 | 2 | 
--------|
| 6     |
| 4 | 5 |
--------|
| 9     |
| 7 | 8 |
---------
```

Assume modern browser and no frameworks.

I started by trying the obvious, just add `style="float:left"` to the `<td>` element, but that essentially doesn't do anything.

I tried Googling for "float a table cell" and found this question [Why float and text-align behave different in a td?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333176/why-float-and-text-align-behave-different-in-a-td), but that's from 2014, many browser versions ago, and it's anyway talking about markup *inside the TD*, while what I want is to actually *float the TD within the row*.

Can it be done in 2020?

Here's the original HTML

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here's the first failed attempt:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td style="float: left">3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is to reset a few display properties but loosing the initial table-layout for the whole table and setting it back to each tr. columns through trs won't be matching unless `table-layout:fixed` is involved:

```css
tr {
  display:table;
}
table, 
td {
  border:solid 1px;
}
tr td:nth-child(3) {
  display:table-caption;
  background:gray;
  margin:0 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```